# AJAX insert makes multiple entries but no data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to put together a script that allows me to update my database with a blocked ip address using ajax so that i do not need to leave the page.  At the moment when i press the block button it provides a success message, however when i look at the database, the date is updated which is done using now so it doesn't actually get a variable.  However the other two fields are empty, but i can not seem to find where the problem is, i am new to ajax and so any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

The form

```
<div id="insert_response"></div>
<!-- Form: the action="javascript:insert()"calls the javascript function "insert" into        ajax_framework.js -->
<form action="javascript:insert()" method="post" class="block">
<div align="center">
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>"/>
<input name="ip" type="hidden" id="ip" value="<?php echo "$ip"; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="block" value="Block"/>&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

The Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form.block').submit(function () {
var id = $(this).find('.id').attr('value');
var ip = $(this).find('.ip').attr('value');
// ...
});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "id="+ id +"& ip="+ ip,
        success: function(){
            $('form#block').hide(function()    {$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
```

The Ajax Frame Work

```
function createObject() {
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();


var nocache = 0;
function insert() {
// Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = "Just a second..."
// Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues      about character encoding.
var ip = encodeURI(document.getElementById('ip').value);
var id = encodeURI(document.getElementById('id').value);
// Set te random number to add to URL request
nocache = Math.random();
// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'ajax.php?id='+id+'&ip='+ip+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
function insertReply() {
if(http.readyState == 4){
var response = http.responseText;
// else if login is ok show a message: "Site added+ site URL".
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = 'Added:'+response;
}
}
```

And Lastly the Php

```
$id = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id']));
$ip = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ip']));
$addClient  = "INSERT INTO ipdata (ip_address, ip_check_id, date_blocked) VALUES ('$ip','$id', NOW())";
mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try doing an alert in your javascript with values of `id` and `ip`? I'm pretty sure when you say:

```
$(this).find('.id').attr('value');
```

You are telling it find a **class** named `id`. Your actual element doesn't say `class="id"` rather it says `id="id"` which is accessed using `#` instead of `.`

Try this instead:

```
var id = $('#id').attr('value');
var ip = $('#ip').attr('value');
```

Comment: OK thanks, now it doesn't seem to be doing anything, what i have just noticed is that after the inital blank spaces in the database additional fields have appeared contaiing [object HTMLCollection] [obje

Comment: for the two fields, these must have been delayed as they were not there initially

Answer (score 0):

The success message you are getting back is simply telling you that the ajax call was successful. Meaning that it connected to the server and got a response back. It has nothing to do with the server side php script. You should check the response coming back from the server and see what it says. You can see this with firebug or simply alert() or console.log() the response.

You should also check the data being sent to the server as well. You could be sending an empty id or ip address. You can view this info in firebug as well.

Comment: Cool, i have never really used firebug and didn't realise it could be used like that,much appreciated.  it returned the following which makes it look like it is passing the ip and id varibales

Comment: POST ajax.php?id=25023&ip=80.40.134.120&nocache = 0.3251394215039909

Comment: OK that last snippet of code was in the response box and the following is what is in the sent box:  ip [object HTMLCollection]
id [object HTMLCollection]  This is what appears to be being added to the database after a delay and as a second entry.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I'd recommend just using $('form').serialize() to get the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(){
        $('form#block').hide(function() { $('div.success').fadeIn();});

    }
});
```

This allows you to avoid mistakes when pulling form data to a processing script.